# How to use Ruby tap method to pre-fill seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, seeding

I am using Ruby `s tap method in my seed.rb like this:-

```
 PaymentMode.find_or_create_by(name: "Cash").tap do |pm|
  pm.instrument = false
  pm.bank_account_allocation = false
  pm.save!
 end
```

In schema.rb, PaymentMode model looks like this:-

```
  create_table "payment_modes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.boolean "instrument", null: false
    t.boolean "bank_account_allocation"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_payment_modes_on_name", unique: true
  end
```

I want that if someone updates the seed file (for e.g. someone can update pm.bank_account_allocation = true) and then run `rake db:seed`, the respective payment_mode's data should be updated, that's why I am using `find_or_create_by` It was working fine but after I added null: false constraint in my PaymentMode (see schema), I am getting this error:-

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "instrument" violates not-null constraint
```

Can I workaround this error? If not, is there a way I can put data in my seed.rb, so that if someone updates the seed, it should update the respective ActiveRecord Object?

P.S. I don't want to keep the constrained column inside the find_or_create_by params like this `PaymentMode.find_or_create_by(name: "Cash", instrument: false).tap` , as it would create another object if someone updates instrument: false to instrument: true

Comment: I believe the error occurs when you run `rails db:migrate`, correct? If that's the case, it's simply because your already have some `PaymentMode` records so creating the column without specifying a default would mean assigning it with a `nil` value which obviously is what you specified in your migration to not have.

Comment: Error occurs when I run rake db:seed, please read the question again

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I don't think it's possible with `#find_or_create_by`. Probably the easiest thing would be to break it down to multiple methods.

Comment: Maybe you can use [create_with](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/create_with)  `PaymentMode.create_with(instrument: false).find_or_create_by(name: "Cash")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with `tap` method. `find_or_create` call, literally, `violates not-null constraint`. In `tap` you are working with existing object, which cannot be written to database with arguments you specified in 
`find_or_create_by`. There are also consequent calls of `create` and `update` instead of just `create`.

There is another method of doing this which works just like tap, but in block you work with object before it's written to database:

```
PaymentMode.where(name: "Cash").first_or_create do |pm|
  pm.instrument = false
  pm.bank_account_allocation = false
end
```

As for me... I'd just use `find_or_initialize_by` and `save` instead.

Comment: Yes, this no longer gived me PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR, but when I have validation in my rails app like `validates :name, :instrument, :bank_account_allocation, presence: true` , I get this error:-   `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Instrument can't be blank, Bank account allocation can't be blank`

Comment: Well, thats because `false.blank?` is `true`. Try another validation as `validates :instrument, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }` or `exclusion: { in: [nil]}`

Comment: Have a look at [Active Record Validations Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). All these questions are thoroughly considered there